# Setting a property of an item in a child list using Func<T, object>

Tags: c#, .net, lambda

I have a parent and child items that have properties:

```
public class Parent
{
    public bool IsValid { get; set; }
    public Child ChildItem { get; set; }
    public List<ChildListItem> ChildList { get; set; }
}

public class ChildItem
{
    public bool IsValid { get; set; }
}

public class ChildListItem
{
    public bool IsValid { get; set; }
}
```

I have a function that takes a generic list of functions to set values:

```
foreach (Func<T, object> function in functions)
{
    function.Invoke(Parent);
}
```

The functions are populated like:

```
public Func<T, object>[] functions { get; set; }

this.functions = FunctionsToArray<Parent>(x => x.IsValid = true,
                                               x.Child.IsValid = true);
```

For reference:

```
public static Func<T, object>[] FunctionsToArray<T>(params Func<T, object>[] functions)
{
    return functions.ToArray();
}
```

What I'd like to do is to set each of the child list items, something like:

```
this.functions = FunctionsToArray<Parent>(x => x.IsValid = true,
                                               x.Child.IsValid = true,
                                               x.ChildList.<something>.IsValid = true);
```

Suggestions/comments/anything would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I think you actually meant to use `Action<Parent>` instead of `Func<Parent, object>` since none of your example lamba expressions actually return anything.  If that's the case then you just need a lambda expression that will iterate the list and set the values, that can be done with a regular `foreach`

```
x => { foreach(var cli in x.ChildList) cli.IsValid = true; }
```

Or since the collection is a `List` you can use it's `ForEach` method

```
x => x.ChildList.ForEach(cli => cli.IsValid = true)
```

You could even create a single lambda that will do all three

```
x => 
{
    x.IsValid = true;
    x.Child.IsValud = true;
    foreach(var cli in x.ChildLIst)
        cli.IsValid = true;
}
```

Comment: Awesome, just what I want, and yes Action vs Func is more appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
x => x.ChildList.ForEach(childListItem => childListItem.IsValid = true)
```